# OpenMP wrong results when more than 1 thread used

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

## Preface

I know there are many similar titled questions. I read quite all of them, but I post this one since the causes might different from all those cases. And I would appreciate your judgement and advices.

**IMPORTANT**: I would also love to provide a minimal reproducible example, but unfortunately the code involved is quite large and dependent on some pieces I could not even share here. I'll try to explain it as best as possible. I will nevertheless provide a minimal example (working, no *erroneous* results there) which tries to give the idea of the code structure.

## Core explanation

### The starting point

The main code block I am trying to parallelise is made up of multiple nested loops, of which I want to *explicitly* parallelise only the outer one, which goes from 1 to 4:

```fortran-modern
!$omp parallel do &
!$omp   default(firstprivate), &
!$omp   private(idir, timer, zone_title), &
!$omp   shared(DIRS_CH, ROTATIONS, NLimsP1, COORDS_DIR_CH, LIM_SIGN_DIRS &
!$omp          , policies, limits, df_I_ref, df_J_ref, msh_ZoneLimsInterestModes &
!$omp          , bases_ch, refmts, deltas, basePts, base_i &
!$omp          , struct_data, wd, settings, logger_debug &
!$omp          , id_im_last, maxF, NLims, getBFM_msh &
!$omp          , NFREQS, NNODES, NNODESL, NLIBS, NLIBSL &
!$omp          , NMODES, NMODES_EFF, MODES &
!$omp          , NPSDEL, NTCOMPS, NDIRS, TCOMPS, DIRS &
!$omp          , msh_izone, msh_totNPts, m3mf_msh_ptr_), &
!$omp   num_threads(4)
do idir = 1, N_DIRS
   ! step 1: general setup
   ...
   do ilim = 1, NLims
      ! step 2: other (more specific) setup
      ...
      ! HERE: main computation
      call rz%compute()
   enddo
   ! step 3: non relevant stuff..
   ...
enddo ! n dirs
!$omp end parallel do
```

### The main computing (type-bound) procedure

As commented in the previous code snippet, the main computation happens in the `compute()` procedure of the (OMP *threadprivate*) DT-variable `rz` (**NOTE**: in the code example, it is simulated via the `proc_2()` procedure):

```fortran
module subroutine compute(this)
   ...
   use omp_lib
   implicit none
   ...
   real(RDP), allocatable :: rres(:, :), intg(:)
   ...

   ! some computation based on *this instance's state
   ...

   allocate(intg(...))

   ! now invoking the main computing function pointer
   rres(:, 1) = getBFM_msh(...)
   
   ! for each of these calls, the local integral gets updated
   intg(:) = rres(:, 1) * somevar ! at first usage only assignment!!
   ...
   intg(:) = intg(:) + rres(:, 1) * somevar ! then, increment

   ! NOTE: this is done many times, even in some do loops !
   ...
   ...

   ! Once local integral is computed, global is updated and data dumped onto a global unit
   ! NOTE: critical to avoid data races and to guard file access to one thread only.
   !$omp critical
   m3mf_msh_ptr_ = m3mf_msh_ptr_ + intg   ! update main integral (shared OMP variable)

   call dumpData(this, rres)
   !$omp end critical
end subroutine
```

### The main computing function pointer

The main actual computation happens in the (pointed) function `getBFM_msh()`, which given some inputs, returns the computation, which is then integrated somehow to retrieve the final results.
Here, namy nested loops lives. However, the most relevant thing (in my opinion) is that, after the first, I make use of **LAPACK** routine `dgesvd()`:

```fortran
module function procPtr_(...) result(rres)
   ...
   
   ! internal data allocation
   ...
   
   do itc = 1, NTCOMPS   ! first loop

      ...
      call dgesvd(&
              'O' &           ! min(M,N) columns of U are overwritten on array A (saves memory)
            , 'N' &           ! no rows of V are computed
            , NNODESL    &    ! n. of rows M
            , NNODESL    &    ! n. of cols N
            , S_uvw_w1   &    ! A matrix (overwritten with left-singular vectors)
            , NNODESL    &
            , D_S_uvw_w1 &    ! singular values
            , tmpv       &    ! U
            , 1          & 
            , tmpv       &    ! VT
            , 1          &
            , MSHR_SVD_WORK  &
            , MSHR_SVD_LWORK &
            , MSHR_SVD_INFO  &
         )

      ! Some other computations, which lead to  "rres"
      ...
   enddo   ! itc
end function
```

in which `tmpv`, `S_uvw_w1` and `D_S_uvw_w1` are locally declared, while `MSHR_SVD_WORK`, `MSHR_SVD_LWORK` and `MSHR_SVD_INFO` are some global module variables, which are made `firstprivate` (since they are changed at each call to `dgesvd()`) for each thread passing through.

## The main problem

Now, all this works setting OMP to only 1 thread.
Results are faulty as soon as the number is set to > 1.
Doing some debug printing, I noticed differences (between 1T and 4T) right after each call to `dgesvd()`, to the variable(s) (i.e. eigenvectors) S_uvw_w1, which for this case is both input and output. So I fear that something goes wrong at this level.

The only reason I can think of is the possibility that LAPACK routine is by itself parallelised, and something goes wrong in the nesting of parallelism.

Because otherwise, I am really struggling to see what I could have missed in order for it to give the correct results..

## Example code:

```fortran
module mod1

   implicit none
   integer :: sum_ = 0, ival_ = 0

   procedure(interf), pointer :: procPtr_ => null()
   abstract interface
      function interf(ival) result(ires)
         integer, intent(in) :: ival
         integer :: ires
      end function
   end interface

contains

   function ifunc1(ival) result(ires)
      integer, intent(in) :: ival
      integer :: ires

      if (mod(ival, 2) == 0) then
         ires = ival * 2
      else
         ires = ival
      endif
   end function

end module


program main

   use omp_lib
   use mod1
   implicit none

   procPtr_ => ifunc1
   call proc_1()
   print *, ' total sum = ', sum_

contains

   subroutine proc_1()
      integer :: i, j

      ! from some previous computations..
      sum_ = 10

      !$omp parallel do default(firstprivate) shared(sum_) &
      !$omp   num_threads(4)
      do i = 1, 4
         do j = 1, 10
            ival_ = i * j
            call proc_2()
         enddo
      enddo
      !$omp end parallel do
   end subroutine

   subroutine proc_2()
      integer :: j, temp_

      temp_ = procPtr_(ival_)

      !$omp critical
      sum_ = sum_ + temp_
      !$omp end critical
   end subroutine

end program
```

Comment: *"The only reason I can think of is the possibility that LAPACK routine is by itself parallelised"*: even if it is, it has no reason to be an issue.

Comment: General comment: using global variables inside parallel regions is potentially an absolute mess. In your "Example code" `ival_` is privatised in `proc1()` thanks to the `firstprivate` directive, but `proc2()` will refer anyway to the global variable defined in `mod1`. So, don't do that.

Comment: Depending on what exact implementation of LAPACK and BLAS you are using the routines may 1. indeed be threaded internally, but that does not have to be a problem, 2. not be thread-safe when called from multiple threads. Not just any subroutine can be called concurrently, it must be thread-safe. For example, `save`d local variables are a problem. Please tell us which exact LAPACK and BLAS library version you are using.

Comment: @PierU I use `ival_` in the example not in the right way as you correctly point out. However, in the actual code there's no such situation.

Comment: In fact, I explicitly declare what's shared for what is read-only, so to avoid doing unnecessary copies. Does still applies the global variables comment?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I compile locally (taken from official GitHub repo) the BLAS and LAPACK routines and link statically to them.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава your comment gave me the hint to try putting a critical region enclosing the calls to `dgesvd()` as test. 
It now gives very close results (still not 100% the same, probably due to machine errors).
I checked the .vfproj file of LAPACK, it uses /Qauto not /Qsave. But it clearly shows that maybe MT call to it is not thread-safe.

Comment: So you are probably using the so-called reference implementations of BLAS and LAPACK. Those are not the only ones. There are various highuperformance implementations compatible with the reference implementations like MKL, OpenBLAS (which also contains LAPACK) and others. You always have to check the thread safety for each individual implementation and it could also differ for various subroutines.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891296/are-the-lapack-routines-thread-safe  Normally, they should be thread safe.

Comment: What about your work arrays, such as `MSHR_SVD_WORK`. Are they private?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава they should be `firstprivate` since I do not list them in the `shared` directive. Is it? Or, should I explicitly put them into a `private` directive?

Comment: I see, yes, they should follow the default clause if they explicitly appear in that parallel region. But from that simplified snippet with many parts missing it is not clear that they do appear there.

Comment: To be sure, compile all the code in your project (including BLAS/LAPACK) with /Qopenmp. But the best guess is that your call to `dgesvd` uses some variables/arrays that are not private.